# What iowait values are ok?

Tags: mysql, bottleneck, iostat, iowait

I am trying to find the bottleneck of a server running a fairly busy php/mysql site. My first culprit was io but iostat shows that on average iowait consumes only %3.60 of cpu time. here is the complete result of issuing iostat:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          65.78    0.00    8.52    3.60    0.00   22.10

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              42.36       138.28      1754.70  408630278 5185216128
```

So I am wondering if the iowait is within acceptable range, and if not, whether switching from SATA to SSD would dramatically reduce it?

Comment: could you list what hardware does this server have? like how many disks, type & CPU, RAM?

Comment: Did you take a look at `atop` or `htop` to see if you have any processes is eating RAM or CPU? You can also sort by `IO_RBYTES`, `IO_WBYTES` in `htop`.

Comment: @John/ZFS: The server has Xeon 3330 2.66GHz with 2x2TB WD hard disks and 8GB RAM

Comment: @quanta: The two main consumers of RAM and CPU are mysql and php5-fpm

Answer (score 6):

`iowait`, as a measure of system load, is only a problem inasmuch as it's consuming CPU time that could be reasonably used by other processes.  If you've still got idle CPU time, then high `iowait` (in and of itself) is not a problem.

On the other hand, a high `iowait` **can** be a symptom of a problem; however, you really should be profiling your application to see if time spent in disk I/O is a significant percentage of the total time taken to complete a useful task.  You cannot do this by looking at CPU stats, `top`, `htop`, `iotop`, or any other system-level tool that people will try to recommend.  You need to look at *your application*, and the way it works, to determine if changing disk I/O subsystem would be of any benefit in your application.

Answer (score 3):

Disk utilisation is more important, you can measure that with:

```
iostat -xm 5
```

it will probably say close to 100%

Comment: A bit of a necro-comment, but this answer does not seem to be very relevant with modern architectures any more. [Here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/06/25/why-util-number-from-iostat-is-meaningless-for-mysql-capacity-planning/) is a post that goes into some more detail, in case anyone else is also trying to wrap their head around these concepts.